# Print all values in a value object

Tags: java, debugging

I have to debug an issue which requires me to print all the values of a Value Object that is returned by a web service call. The Value object is a complex object in the sense, it has another object as its member which in turn has another object.

Printing all the values by using get methods is cumbersome. So I was wondering if there is a way to break down the value object by any way to get to a primitive level like String or int or Date and print them all using one API?

I had a look at the below question but my prob is that I don't have access to the source code of the value object. The sources are in obfuscated jar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413001/how-to-print-values-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for one of the Apache Commons utilites.

- [BeanUtils.describe()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html#toString-java.lang.Object-)

These do slightly different things depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: +1 - ReflectionToStringBuilder does a really good job (generally) in these cases.

Comment: 2nd Link does not work.

Comment: Second link is now at: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to discover subfields structure

```
public static void dump(Object o){
    Field[] fields = ReflectUtils.getFields(o.getClass());
    try{
        for(Field field : fields){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(o);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + field.get(o));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```